# How to know where to put parens when passing functions as arguments?

Tags: python, function, probability

Why is it that I get a semantic error when I pass the function `rollDie()` over `checkPascal(numTrials, roll)`, but when I pass the name of it, and then put the parens after the variable, it works as intended? (Please have a look at the code). I have tried playing around with it and also looking but I can't seem to word it correctly to find the answer anywhere.

This would be greatly appreciated as I cannot seem to figure it out. It's not a huge deal and this question is not even part of the classwork. We are learning about Monte Carlo methods in my OpenCourseWare MITx class, and I randomly came across this. I didn't know why the parens were where they were. I assumed they should be in the def line. I am taking a free online class that was previously recorded, so I don't have an instructor to speak to who could tell me. Thanks.

```
import random

def rollDie():
    """returns a random int between 1 and 6"""
    return random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6])

def checkPascal(numTrials, roll):
    yes = 0.0
    for i in range(numTrials):
        for j in range(24):
            d1 = roll #correct line would be d1 = roll()
            d2 = roll #d2 = roll()
            if d1 == 6 and d2 == 6:
                yes += 1
                break
    print 'Probability of losing =', 1.0 - yes/numTrials

checkPascal(10000, rollDie()) #incorrect code
#correct code would be checkPascal(10000, rollDie)
```

As I understand it, the 'roll' is just a variable, and variables can't have arguments, at least I thought that. It just seems intuitively wrong. Is this because it is a weakly typed language? I am very curious. Thanks.

Comment: `rollDie()` is a number, `rollDie` is a function.

Comment: Python is strongly typed. Strong/weak typing doesn't have anything to do with static/dynamic typing.

Answer (score 6):

Passing just the name `rollDie` passes the **function** `rollDie`. That's why putting parens after `roll` further down works, you are **calling** the function referenced by the variable `roll`.

Passing `rollDie()` evaluates that function, and returns `random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6])` (and in that case `roll` is an integer)

Try:

```
print rollDie
print rollDie()
```

to see the difference.